# Program Flow AppInventor

Tags: android, list, barcode-scanner, app-inventor

Alright... No one laugh... I am working on an app in MIT/Google Appinventor. Here's a rundown:

- Scans a barcode then runs the pictured function.
- If the item is in the list then
     Find that items position index in the inventory list.
     Use that items index, to increment the value in the quantity list by 1.
- If the item is not in the list then
     Add that item to the inventory, and add a "1" to the quantity.

I can't see why it won't work so I was just checking to see if there are any obvious flaws in my logic. If the logic looks solid, then I should be able to figure out the Appinventor problem to make it work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your function translated (accurately?) into pseudo-code to help with my own understanding (and hopefully others'):

```
function addItem:
  if inventoryList.contains(scannerResult):
    inventoryPosition = inventoryList.positionOf(scannerResult)
    quantityPosition = quantityList.positionOf(scannerResult)
    quantityItem = quantityList.selectListItemAt(quantityPosition)
    quantityList.insert(quantityItem at inventoryPosition)
  else
    inventoryList.add(scannerResult)
    quantityList.add(1)
```

The problem appears to be in the logic when the scanner result is already in the list.  I don't know the relevant app-inventor functions, but I think that you want something more like:

```
  if inventoryList.contains(scannerResult):
    inventoryPosition = inventoryList.positionOf(scannerResult)
    quantity = quantityList.selectListItemAt(inventoryPosition)
    quantityList.setListItemAt(quantityPosition to quantity + 1)
```

That last line is the bit I don't know how to translate into app-inventor language, but hopefully it's enough to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

@blahdiblah made a good [analysis of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19994061/1545993).
The solution with App Inventor looks like this: 
instead of the **insert list item** block you have to use the **replace list item** block

[image]